# Getting all Sentinel user related to roles

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentinel

How can I get all users related to user roles by Sentinel? And how can I get all users in Sentinel? This does not work:

```
Sentinel::all()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this to get all users related to a specific role.

```
$role = Sentinel::findRoleById(1);
// or findRoleBySlug('admin'); for example
$users = $role->users()->with('roles')->get();
```

and you can access the first user (and so on and so forth like this)

```
dd($users[0]['attributes']);
```

and to get all users you can do this:

```
$test = Sentinel::getUserRepository();
dd($test);
```